# JavaScript download file from URL and submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I've got CreateFile dialog with several options: "FromFile", "Drag'n'Drop" and URL.
Is there any way to  download and submit file only using JS?
I'm tried to use:

```
new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)()
```

but its no longer deprecated.

Comment: Set the proper headers for the URL, and the file will download automagically.

Comment: I don't need to download file to user. I need to get file from one server and put to another through JS.